# IOS error compiling source code?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I downloaded a source code for an iOS coloring book [from github](https://github.com/byronsanchez/coloring-book-ios) :

When I try to compile I get these errors, and I don't understand what they mean:

```
    0 clang 0x0000000100c57bb2 main + 12932498
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

Comment: I don't know the solution but it does say that you should submit a bug report to Apple -- I think you should.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions? I tried to build it after just cloning the primary directory, got lots of problems, then re-read the Instructions and found this:

```
INSTRUCTIONS

  Clone the coloring-book-ios repository, or alternatively, clone
  your fork of the coloring-book-ios repository, along with its
  submodules.

  For git version 1.6.5 or higher, run:

    git clone --recursive https://github.com/byronsanchez/coloring-book-ios.git
    cd coloring-book-ios
    Assets/Scripts/build.sh all

  For other versions of git, run:

    git clone https://github.com/byronsanchez/coloring-book-ios.git
    cd coloring-book-ios
    git submodule update --init
    Assets/Scripts/build.sh all
```

Once I followed the 1.6.5 or higher (and ignored the build.sh warning as it instructions you to do in that file) everything built just fine using Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: sorry i dont really understand, how can i ignore the build.sh warning ? i dont really understand the instructions im sorry English is not my first language, please give me more details, thank you

Comment: When the build.sh asks whether to continue or not, type "y" (that is the character y) and hit return. Only then can you open the project. I opened the build.sh using vi, and it says at the top to ignore the warning and to enter y.

Comment: okay i'm 80% understanding, the way i run the project on the xcode is to click on "coloring-bock.xcodeproj" and then click run from the product menu, but it seems like i need to "Run" the build.sh file first if that is right ? can you please tell me how to do this ? thanks again so much.

Comment: okay i actually managed to run the build.sh file and selected all option, but i still get the same error ?

Comment: To your first question - you MUST do the first step in the answer completely before opening the project with Xcode. If you already downloaded and tried to build, then totally delete it and start again. Also, what version of Xcode are you using - I explicitly said I used the latest official version 4.6.3. If you do not have that version now, then get it. Also, what device type did you set? I tried iPhone simulator. I did not run it, just built it. So try build first.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the project references Toast+UIView.h but doesn't contain that category at the root level.  NIBs, Raw, and Vendor are submodules of the main project.